# Icons as x-axis labels in R - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

(This is an extension to the question [Icons as x-axis labels in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29922673/icons-as-x-axis-labels-in-r). It looks for a *ggplot* solution instead of a *plot* one. Since `ggplot` is based on *grid* and `plot` is based on *graphics*, the approach is very different)

I would like to plot something like this [(from this paper)](http://wwwconference.org/www2008/papers/pdf/p665-adamic.pdf) where icons, in this case small graphs, are used as tick labels.

[image]

The accepted answer from the original question is:

```
library(igraph)    
npoints <- 15
y <- rexp(npoints)
x <- seq(npoints)

# reserve some extra space on bottom margin (outer margin)
par(oma=c(3,0,0,0))
plot(y, xlab=NA, xaxt='n',  pch=15, cex=2, col="red")
lines(y, col='red', lwd=2)

# graph numbers 
x = 1:npoints   

# add offset to first graph for centering
x[1] = x[1] + 0.4
x1 = grconvertX(x=x-0.4, from = 'user', to = 'ndc')
x2 = grconvertX(x=x+0.4, from = 'user', to = 'ndc')

for(i in x){  

  print(paste(i, x1[i], x2[i], sep='; '))

  # remove plot margins (mar) around igraphs, so they appear bigger and 
  # `figure margins too large' error is avoided
  par(fig=c(x1[i],x2[i],0,0.2), new=TRUE, mar=c(0,0,0,0))
  plot(graph.ring(i), vertex.label=NA)  
}
```

[image]

How can we make a similar plot using **ggplot**?

This is the closer I get:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grImport)
library(igraph)

npoints <- 5
y <- rexp(npoints)
x <- seq(npoints)

pics  <- vector(mode="list", length=npoints)
for(i in 1:npoints){
  fileps <- paste0("motif",i,".ps")
  filexml <- paste0("motif",i,".xml")

  # Postscript file
  postscript(file = fileps, fonts=c("serif", "Palatino"))
  plot(graph.ring(i), vertex.label.family="serif", edge.label.family="Palatino")
  dev.off()

  # Convert to xml accessible for symbolsGrob
  PostScriptTrace(fileps, filexml)
  pics[i] <- readPicture(filexml)
}
xpos <- -0.20+x/npoints
my_g <- do.call("grobTree", Map(symbolsGrob, pics, x=xpos, y=0))
qplot(x, y, geom = c("line", "point")) + annotation_custom(my_g, xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymax=0.4, ymin=0.3)
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Icons as x-axis labels in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29922673/icons-as-x-axis-labels-in-r)

Comment: Not at all!. This one asks for a ggplot solution.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need a solution in ggplot2?

Comment: Three: a) use the capabilities (ease of use, functions, etc) of ggplot to further improve the plot in the near future. (b) I use ggplot in other parts of my code (homogeneity) (c) fun and curiosity.

Comment: is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905101/how-can-i-use-a-graphic-imported-with-grimport-as-axis-tick-labels-in-ggplot2-u

Comment: @hrbrmstr note also that use opts( axis.text.x = my_axis()) which is deprecated

Comment: Regarding `ops()`, I think in many cases you can directly replace `opts()` with `theme()` and it'll get you the same thing.

Comment: @Alex however it does not work for `axis.text.x`. Theme is more restricted to colors and so.

Comment: @hrbrmstr the solution you link does not work at all for the most recent versions of `ggplot2`

Comment: grob editing has to be the way to go, tho. it's not fun, and if i had more spare cycles I'd give it a go.

Comment: I'm playing with it in the meanwhile :)

Answer (score 3):

This builds of your attempt.

(I used `set.seed(1)` before the `rexp` function and also tweaked the graph to increase the edge thickness: `plot(graph.ring(i), vertex.label=NA, edge.width=30)`)

Continuing from above:

```
# Initial plot
p <- qplot(x, y, geom = c("line", "point")) 

# Use the plot to get the x-positions of the labels
g <- ggplotGrob(p)    
xpos <- g$grobs[[grep("axis-b", g$layout$name)]]$children[[2]]$grobs[[2]]$x

# Create grob tree 
my_g <- do.call("grobTree", Map(symbolsGrob, pics, x=xpos, y=0.5))

# Make second plot
# Add extra space under the plot for the images 
# Remove x-axis details
# Note the annotation is below the lower y-axis limit
# The limits were selected by inspection
p2 <- p + annotation_custom(my_g, xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymax=-0.1, ymin=-0.2) + 
            theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
                  plot.margin=unit(c(1,1,2,1), "cm"))

# remove clipping so the images render
g <- ggplotGrob(p2)
g$layout$clip[g$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

There will be a way to do this properly / in line with the lovely previous solution, but anyways ...

Comment: With ggplot2 version 3.0.0, you can now disable clipping with `my_plot + coord_cartesian(clip = 'off')`, which is simpler than the grid solution (i.e. `g$layout$clip[g$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"`)

Comment: @bschneidr ; please feel free to update the answer if there a better ways to do it, or grob paths have broken etc