# absoluteGrob not found (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

The function `absoluteGrob {ggplot2}` shows a behavior that I am not able to debug. I have `ggplot2` installed and I can see the help page by `?absoluteGrob`.

However, R does not find it when I try to use it:

```
> absoluteGrob
Error: object 'absoluteGrob' not found
```

More particularly, I try to execute the following code (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8922470/1219701)  to plot some graphs as x-labels):

```
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)
library(grImport)
library(igraph)


npoints <- 3

y <- rexp(npoints)
x <- seq(npoints)

pics  <- vector(mode="list", length=npoints)
for(i in 1:npoints){
  fileps <- paste0("motif",i,".ps")
  filexml <- paste0("motif",i,".xml")

  # Postscript file
  postscript(file = fileps, fonts=c("serif", "Palatino"))
  plot(graph.ring(i), vertex.label.family="serif", edge.label.family="Palatino")
  dev.off()

  # Convert to xml accessible for symbolsGrob (my_axis)
  PostScriptTrace(fileps, filexml)
  pics[i] <- readPicture(filexml)
}


my_axis <- function () {
    function(label, x = 0.5, y = 0.5, ...) {
        absoluteGrob(
           do.call("gList", mapply(symbolsGrob, pics[label], x, y, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)),
           height = unit(1.5, "cm")
      )
    }
  }

qplot(factor(c("a", "b", "c")), 1:npoints) + scale_x_discrete(labels= my_axis())
```

But I get the error:

```
Error in scale$labels(breaks) : could not find function "absoluteGrob"
```

Any help (or alternatives) is welcome.

ggplot2 version:

`ggplot2_1.0.1`

**Edit**

Even in the simple case...

It does not work:

```
library(ggplot2)
absoluteGrob
```

It does:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot2:::absoluteGrob
```

Comment: What version of `ggplot` are you using? Try updating to the newest version if you aren't on that already.

Comment: I'm using ggplot2_1.0.1

Comment: @Alex please see my edit. ggplot2:::absoluteGrob finds it. :-O

Comment: Aha! Figured it out. It's in `ggplot2` but not exported. So you won't even be able to use it by `ggplot2::absoluteGrob(...)`.

Comment: mm I guess that's why if I use the ::: it raises and exception and where traceback says  `stop(gettextf("'%s' is not an exported object from 'namespace:%s'", 
       name, getNamespaceName(ns)), call. = FALSE, domain = NA)`

Comment: also i am not sure the images will turn out as expected - may need a bit of manual tweaking to get the sizes reasonable: `my_g <- do.call("grobTree", Map(symbolsGrob, pics, x=c(0.2, 0.5, 0.8), y=0.5)) ; qplot(1:3, 1:3) + annotation_custom(my_g, xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymax=1.5, ymin=1 )`

Comment: `annotation_custom` ! Thanks! @user20650 feel free to post this as an answer to this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939447/icons-as-x-axis-labels-in-r-ggplot2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you linked to in your post was posted 3 years ago as of this posting, and many things in `ggplot2` have changed since then. At that point, `ggplot2` version 0.9.0 had not yet been released.

According to the [1.0.0 documentation for `absoluteGrob`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/functions/absoluteGrob), it's still experimental, which means that it was certainly experimental at the time of the linked answer. At that point it was likely exported from the `ggplot2` namespace and thus available to the user. That's why the linked answer worked at the time.

However, as of version 1.0.1, it is not exported from the `ggplot2` namespace. So while you're able to view the source and documentation with `ggplot2:::absoluteGrob` (which works for non-exported objects) and `?absoluteGrob`, you will not be able to use it, even by explicitly specifying the namespace via `ggplot2::absoluteGrob`.

According to the source, it simply calls `gTree()`, which is from the `grid` package, with `cl="absoluteGrob"`. You can try that in place of calling `absoluteGrob()` directly. For example, try the following, which will hopefully mimic the desired behavior from `absoluteGrob()`:

```
grlist <- do.call("gList", mapply(symbolsGrob, pics[label], x, y, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))

gTree(children = grlist,
      cl = "absoluteGrob",
      height = unit(1.5, "cm"),
      width = NULL,
      xmin = NULL,
      ymin = NULL,
      vp = NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex ! And how would you call gTree? I'm trying     `gTree(
      do.call("gList", mapply(symbolsGrob, pics[label], x, y, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)))` with no success...

Comment: I'm trying hard... learning more about do.call, gList, gTree... but `unable to find an inherited method for function ‘symbolize’ for signature ‘"NULL"’`

Comment: @alberto: Admittedly I don't know much about `gList` or `gTree`, but with some Googling I think it's because `gTree` isn't recognizing `"absoluteGrob"` as a class...