# change x scale labels to symbols in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wonder whether there is an elegant way to change the x scale labels to symbols, e.g. polygons. Cf. the following figure.

[image: Example figure]

Comment: Should the numbers be in the polygons? Or polygons only?

Comment: It looks a bit complicated to me, but [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905101/how-can-i-use-a-graphic-imported-with-grimport-as-axis-tick-labels-in-ggplot2-u) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939447/icons-as-x-axis-labels-in-r-ggplot2) are two places to start (and are possibly duplicates).  Can you add your coding attempt to do this and where you got stuck?