# image as axis tick ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggridges

I've been searching around for a way to use png images as axis ticks in ggplot2, more precisely in **ggridges**
I've read and tried to replicate answers to these posts, but packages have changed a lot in syntax from the time when they were posted to the date:

[Annotate ggplot with an extra tick and label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824773/annotate-ggplot-with-an-extra-tick-and-label)
[How can I use a graphic imported with grImport as axis tick labels in ggplot2 (using grid functions)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905101/how-can-i-use-a-graphic-imported-with-grimport-as-axis-tick-labels-in-ggplot2-u?noredirect=1&lq=1)
[Icons as x-axis labels in R - ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939447/icons-as-x-axis-labels-in-r-ggplot2)

I'd like to add png (or another kind of) images to tick labels, instead of the labels virginica, setosa and versicolor;

```
library(ggridges)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species)) + geom_density_ridges()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cowplot` package has made this somewhat easier.

Build the plot:

```
library(ggridges)
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species)) + geom_density_ridges()
```

Load the images and use `axis_canvas()` to build a strip of vertical images:

```
library(cowplot)

pimage <- axis_canvas(p, axis = 'y') + 
  draw_image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9f/Iris_virginica.jpg/295px-Iris_virginica.jpg", y = 2.5, scale = 0.5) +
  draw_image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Iris_versicolor_3.jpg/320px-Iris_versicolor_3.jpg", y = 1.5, scale = 0.5) +
  draw_image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/56/Kosaciec_szczecinkowaty_Iris_setosa.jpg/450px-Kosaciec_szczecinkowaty_Iris_setosa.jpg", y = 0.5, scale = 0.5)


# insert the image strip into the plot
ggdraw(insert_yaxis_grob(p, pimage, position = "left"))
```

[image]

Without the `axis.text.y`:

```
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species)) + geom_density_ridges() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())
ggdraw(insert_yaxis_grob(p, pimage, position = "left"))
```

[image]

You could remove also the vertical line, currently I can't find a way of having the image strip on the left-side of the axis line.